# Censored Regression with different limits for some observations

Tags: r, regression, distributions, modeling, censoring

I'm attempting to model some data using regression analysis that has different upper limits for different observations, i.e. there is no universal limit for the entire data set. However I do have observations that have been censored, but the amount of censoring will sometimes change between observations? As I understand it the `censReg` R package accepts one universal upper limit, is there another option either within this package or in another package/language that would allow me to model observations with different upper limits?

If there is no other option then would using a similar approach to zero-inflated models accurately model this behavior? And by that I mean build a model to estimate when an observation might be censored and include that in the final distribution of what I am trying to predict. That's the only approach I can think of that might help with this distribution behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `censReg` only supports a scalar censoring point, i.e., constant over observations.

As an alternative you may use the `crch` package whose `crch()` function supports left and right limits that may be varying over observations. Additionally, it optionally allows to model heteroscedasticity conditional on regressors.

Furthermore, the `survival` package's `survreg()` function also supports arbitrary censoring patterns which have to be set up through a suitable `Surv()` object. It provides more response distributions than the two aforementioned packages.